# ORACLE 11g: RMAN setting to view only full backup

Tags: oracle

We have successfully performed a FULL and INCREMENTAL backups using RMAN. By using "RMAN> LIST BACKUP;" command we are listing all the backups taken by RMAN. But we can see only FULL backup only and no INCREMENTAL backup.

We were assuming if there is any RMAN configuration set to list only FULL backup and also checked the same using "RMAN> SHOW ALL;" command but did not find such setting. Please suggest why the INCREMENTAL backups are not listed in when listing backup using "LIST BACKUP" command.

Below is the configuration of my RMAN utility:

```
RMAN> show all;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORCL are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOA
D TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'G:\INSTALLED_PROGRAM_FILES\ORACLE\APP\ORA\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SNCFORCL.ORA'; # default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"LIST BACKUP" will show all backups. Refer to attached image.
[image]

Please read below article for better understandings.

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96566/rcmquery.htm

You can list rman backups by using below query:

```
select start_time, status, input_type, output_bytes_display, time_taken_display from v$rman_backup_job_details order by start_time desc;
```